# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush breaks the disabled state of a ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-forms

In my Angular app, I've created a custom form element by implementing the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface.

So in my component I correctly implement all methods of that interface, including `setDisabledState`:

```
/**
 * This function is called when the control status changes to or from "disabled".
 * Depending on the value, it will enable or disable the appropriate DOM element.
 *
 * @param isDisabled
 */
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  this.disabled = isDisabled;
}
```

Everything works fine.

The problem is when I change the [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) of my component setting it to `OnPush`.

By doing that, the enable/disable functionality of my component is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by manually triggering the change detection.

We need to inject the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) into our component:

```
import {  ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) { }
```

then use it to manually trigger the change detection whenever the enabled/disabled status changes:

```
setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  this.disabled = isDisabled;
  this.cd.markForCheck(); // this will manually trigger the change detection
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OnPush can only make sense if we are talking about parent / child components communication. when the child has changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush setting and the parent is passing an object as an input to the child.

If you are creating a Reactive Custom Form Control which has its own state. It's good to avoid using onPush. If you want to use, you can manually call the Change detection manually using cdr.markforCheck().

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however in my case I'm just trying to solve an issue on an existing component of a library. So changing the change detection strategy is not my call: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4055